# Запуск функции через промежуток времени C#

Tags: c#, функции, таймер

Здравствуйте. Есть функция, которая обращается к сайту и получает содержимое h2-заголовков с первых 10 страниц. Эта функция выполняется каждые 30 минут. Делаю я это с помощью обычного Timer

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1800000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FH();
    }
```

Собственно, вопрос: не сильно ли такой способ работы нагрузит ПК? Или, может быть, есть более простой и надежный способ?

Comment: Да нормально, можно оставить так, но если хотите чего-то совсем крутого, то можно заюзать Quartz.NET: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: Можно ассинхронно зациклить еще :)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, этот способ вполне нормальный.

Например, в игровом движке Unity на обработке каждого кадра исполняется код программиста в методе Update :)

Оптимальнее сделать просто нереально :)

Использовать внешние библиотеки для такой задачи - излишне.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал Вам использовать таймер `System.Timers.Timer` и использовать его событие `Timer.Elapsed`. Преимущества данного подхода очевидны: метод-делегат, подписанный на это событие выполняется в свободном потоке из пула потоков `ThreadPool`, таким образом ваш основной UI-поток не блокируется на время выполнения трудоемкой операции. Если метод-делегат, подписанный на событие `Elapsed` должен что-либо изменять на форме, то можете воспользоваться `Invoke` и `MethodInvoker` для проброса через контекст синхронизации необходимой информации в UI-поток формы, где `RefreshMethodForInvoke()` - метод, в котором идет обращение к контролам на форме:

```
 private void tDGVOverviewRefresh_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            tDGVOverviewRefresh.Stop();

            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(RefreshMethodForInvoke));
        }
```

Документация:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx